# How to add checkbox for each row in table html with php embedded and update its value in database(Postgresql)?

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have already fetch the record from the database. It is shown on the html table. But it is still Non editable mode. I want to make sure the record shown is completely okay and update its Boolean value in the database. Otherwise it should be shown as red in color which are not approved i.e they are incorrect. 
May be this can be easy. But please help me working this out. *Sharing my code*.

```
 <div class="login-signup-head">Edit Table</div>
    <table>
    <tbody>
         <thead>
              <tr class="tredit">
                <!-- <th width="10"></th> -->
                <th contenteditable="true"> Id </th>
                <th contenteditable="true"> University Id </th>
                <th contenteditable="true"> Name </th>
                <th contenteditable="true"> College Id </th>
                <th width="100"> </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                          <?php 
         foreach($student_data as $row){

          ?>
            <tr class="tredit"> 
                <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $row['university_id']; ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $row['college_id']; ?></td> 
                <td><input type='button' class='editable' onclick="table_edit()" value='Edit'/>
                <input type='button' class='tabledelete' onclick="table_update()" value='Delete'></td> 
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
     </div>
       </div>
       </div>
    <!--    </form> -->
       </div>  
    </div>
    </tbody>
         </table>
```

This above code is called with the help of function in controller class whose code is below:

```
 public function tableedit(){



          if($this->session->userdata('university_id')){

              /*if($this->input->server("REQUEST_METHOD") === "POST"){*/

                  // $data['user_id'] = $this->session->userdata('university_id');
                 /*$data['name'] = $this->input->post('college_name');
                 $data['college_id'] =$this->input->post('college_id');
             $insert = $this->home_model->addCollege($data);
              $data['success'] = 'college added successfully';
              }*/




              $user_id =  $this->session->userdata('university_id');
              $data['user_id'] = $user_id;
              $data['student_data'] = $this->home_model->table_data($user_id);

               $this->load->view('home/new-header',$data);
               // $data['get_social'] = $this->home_model->get_social();*/
               //  $this->load->view('socail', $data);

    //            if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

    //     echo json_encode($response);

    // }

               /*$this->home_model->update_university_password($user_id,$password);*/

               $this->load->view('home/left_university_sidebar',$data);
               $this->load->view('edit_table',$data);

               $this->load->view('home/footer');

          } else {
              $data['error'] = 'Table Cannot be viewed!';
              $this->load->view('home/header');
              $this->load->view('edit_table');
              $this->load->view('home/footer');

          }

      }
```

Now this above code is getting called in the model class i.e where the queries are called.

```
public function table_data($user_id) {

    $this->db->select('id,university_id,name,college_id');
       /*$this->db->where('university_id',trim($user_id));*/
       $this->db->from('college');
       $query = $this->db->get();
       return $query->result_array();

 /* $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id,university_id,name,college_id FROM college");
   $this->db->where('user_id',$university_id);
                   return $query->result_array();*/

}
```

Comment: what have u tried, what is the issue?

Comment: I tried adding the checkbox. But it doesn't appear on the screen. I want to know the code by which i am able to check the record that is already fetched from database.

Answer (score 0):

It is a strange question in all fairness and we cannot code it for you.

But in your view, you need to make your table inside a form, then add a table cell to contain your checkbox.

How you generate your checkbox is up to you, you can use the CI form_helper or you can just code bootstrap checkbox, or use a plain html checkbox. The value of your checkbox you can set like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my_value[]" value="<?php echo $entry_id; ?>">
```

Where entry id is your row id or identifier you set. You collect your input something like this

```
$my_data = $this->input->post('my_value');
```

You now have an array of all your checked values. Run through these and do whatever you want.

As for showing items in red that do not fit a particular criteria, a simple if statement in your view will do that, either displaying an entirely different piece of HTML or setting a class to use on the row, table cell or text.

I hope this helps in some way, but your question was rather vague to begin with.

Good luck with your website,

Best wishes,

Paul.

Comment: Thanks @Paul. Let me try it out. I also did the input checkbox code in a similar way but didn't see anything! Anyways if i'll get stuck again i'll get back to you.